# Node.js loads locally but not on heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm pretty new to Heroku and am having some trouble getting my simple node app up and accessible.

I can run the app locally fine but once it's pushed to Heroku, I get Application Error.

I've added a Procfile as well as a 'start' value in my package.json but regardless, I consistently get "application error."

I know that similar questions have already been asked but the solutions there haven't solved the issue.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "twiliosender",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.4.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cool-ascii-faces": "^1.3.4",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "node": "0.0.0",
    "twilio": "^2.10.0"
  }
}
```

Procfile:

```
web: node index.js
```

index.js

```
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('/static/index.html',{root: __dirname})

});


app.post('/send', 
    function(req, res){
    res.send(client.messages.create({
    to: ""
    , from: ""
    , body: possibleTextMessages[picker()],
    }, function(err, message) { 
    console.log(message.sid); 
})
)});


app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the app.listen() call to accept any ip has resolved the issue in case anyone comes across a similar problem.

`app.listen(process.env.PORT, '0.0.0.0', function(err) {
  console.log("Started listening on %s", app.url);`